# Setting limit to total physical memory available in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, kernel, memory-address

I know that I am supposed to set `mem=MEMORY_LIMIT`. But I do not know where to go, during runtime, or during boot time, in order to set a limit to the total physical memory that the OS has control of.

I am running I/O benchmarks, and I would like to limit the amount of overall physical memory that is available.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for. Basically, the parameter that sets the total available physical memory is "mem=MEMORY_LIMIT". And this is a kernel boot parameter. You need to add, say "mem=1G" for maximum of 1GB available physical memory to the kernel boot parameter. For more info on how to add kernel boot parameters look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

Comment: The parameter has a slightly different meaning for x86 systems (both 32 and 64 bit): "mem=nn[KMG] […] [X86] Work as limiting max address" ([source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt)). Due to reserved memory sections, its value on x86 will be higher than the amount of memory to make available to the OS. Example: Had to use `mem=6700M` to get 5365 out of 6144 MiB (6 GiB) physically available memory.

Answer (score 6):

Edit your kernel boot parameters in `lilo.conf`, `grub.conf`, `grub.cfg`, or `menu.lst` (which one depends on your particular distro and bootloader; check your distro's documentation for more detail) to include the parameter `mem=512M` (or whatever size you want to emulate) on the line specifying your kernel parameters.

For instance, in Grub, there should be a line that says something like `kernel /boot/vmlinuz param1=val1 param2=val2`. Add the `mem=512M` to that list of parameters. You can create separate entries for your boot menu by copying these entire definitions, renaming them, and configuring each with a different amount of memory, so you can quickly boot with different settings.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Brian Campbell's list, for the uBoot bootloader on the BeagleBone / Black devices, edit the kernel paramters in `/boot/uboot/uEnv.txt`
Add or modify the line `mmcargs=setenv bootargs mem=512M` [tested with Debian]

Use `> free` before and after [reboot] to confirm the modification

Answer (score 2):

I've followed the instructions in [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) that KZcoding mentioned (part: Permanently Add a Kernel Boot Parameter)

My Linux is (vm in virtualbox):

```
Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Before setting:

```
yavuz@ubuntu:~$ free -m
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3630         305        3010           6         314        3264
Swap:          3767           0        3767
```

Just changed this line in `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="mem=2G"
```

then restart the server. After restart:

```
yavuz@ubuntu:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2000         298        1385           4         315        1651
Swap:          3767           0        3767
```

Comment: I suppose we need to reboot in order to see the change in available memory?

Comment: On my `Ubuntu 16.04` even after a reboot, the available memory hasn't changed.

Comment: @Stephane did you run `sudo update-grub` after editing `/etc/default/grup`?

Comment: @Yang I solved my issue a long time ago by switching back the mem sticks to the original sticks.

Comment: thank you @Stephane, i've edited the answer and added that we have to restart the server.

Comment: If `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` has a parameter already, add `mem=2G` separating it from the existing parameter using a space. For example, `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="consoleblank=0 mem=2G"`.

Comment: Just restarting the server is not enough. One also needs to run `sudo update-grub` (at least on Ubuntu 20).

Answer (score 0):

A1: Yes, you have to reboot.

A2: The kernel is rather unforgiving with respect to typos. There are no error messages. Could that be your problem? Examples: " mem=512M" and " mem=2G". Don't forget the space following the previous parameter, mem is in lower case, and K, M or G are upper case.