# Kubernetes OOM pod killed because kernel memory grows to much

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, kubernetes, out-of-memory

I am working on a java service that basically creates files in a network file system to store data. It runs in a k8s cluster in a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
When we began to limit the memory in kubernetes (limits: memory: 3Gi), the pods began to be OOMKilled by kubernetes.

At the beginning we thought it was a leak of memory in the java process, but analyzing more deeply we noticed that the problem is the memory of the kernel.
We validated that looking at the file /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.kmem.usage_in_bytes

We isolated the case to only create files (without java) with the DD command like this:

```
for i in {1..50000}; do dd if=/dev/urandom bs=4096 count=1 of=file$i; done
```

And with the dd command we saw that the same thing happened ( the kernel memory grew until OOM). 
After k8s restarted the pod, I got doing a describe pod:

- Last State:Terminated
- Reason: OOMKilled
- Exit Code: 143

Creating files cause the kernel memory grows, deleting those files cause  the memory decreases . But our services store data , so it creates a lot of files continuously, until the pod is killed and restarted because OOMKilled.

We tested limiting the kernel memory using a stand alone docker with the --kernel-memory parameter and it worked as expected. The kernel memory grew to the limit and did not rise anymore. But we did not find any way to do that in a kubernetes cluster.
Is there a way to limit the kernel memory in a K8S environment ?
Why the creation of files causes the kernel memory grows and it is not released ?

Comment: I guess you are setting a limit like https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#meaning-of-memory and you've looked at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/61937 ?

Comment: Is a java process running? Are the files being written to a persistent volume?

Comment: Hello @RyanDawson . This problem happens with a java process writing files and with other programs (non java) that write files. We could reproduce this issue with java and non java programs and with the DD linux command. In the case of a java program, the memory used by java do not grows. The problem is the kernel memory. It seems that writing files needs the memory kernel and it is not released. We are writing the files in a persistent volume, either in a local disk or in a nfs. The result is the same

Comment: Have you tried using different base images? You could also try deploying to different k8s cluster flavours (e.g. minikube and gke). That would help narrow down possible causes.

Comment: I tried using ubuntu latest and alpine latest , in both cases the kernel memory grows and do not decrease when I stop creating files

Comment: You may be able to set a parameter to limit to the container in the Pod. An example of attempting this for CPU - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361658/kubernetes-resource-limits-exceeded You may have to set at OS level if the docker param doesn't do it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484016/setting-limit-to-total-physical-memory-available-in-linux which may mean doing like http://bogdan-albei.blogspot.com/2017/09/kernel-tuning-in-kubernetes.html?m=1

Comment: Hello @RyanDawson, thanks for your comments. I took a look at the sysctl parameters trying to find out a way to set a limit to the kernel memory causing the same effect that the docker parameter --kernel-memory  but I think I need and expert on that subject. In addition to that I could not find why creating files causes the kernel memory grows

Comment: You could try breaking this into separate questions and including in each the steps you've tried. One might be why the memory grows, another how to apply the equivalent of the docker param in k8s and possibly a third on how to do it at the Linux level (you may get lucky and find a kernel expert reads it).

Comment: This issue is very easy to reproduce. I am surprised that there are no a lot of similar cases in the net

Comment: Thanks I will fill separated question on this subject

Comment: Hello @RyanDawson. We found that the problem are the dentry and inodes caches. It is possible to set the parameter vfs_cache_pressure using sysctl.

The documentation is here : https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt

Comment: We did it adding ( thanks for your post) the following to the deployment: `initContainers:
        - name: init-sysctl
          image: busybox
          command:
          - /bin/sh
          - -c
          - |
            sysctl -w vm.vfs_cache_pressure=value 
          securityContext:
            privileged: true`

Comment: But that affects the node, we do not find yet another solution

Comment: Glad you at least found a way and identified what is happening. If you want to edit the question again I can nominate it to be reopened if you like.

Comment: @RyanDawson yes please, I would like that

Comment: Have nominated. Hopefully others agree it is much more specific now.

Comment: @PabloHadziatanasiu what value did you specifically change the `vm.vfs_cache_pressure`?  150? 500?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all this info, it was very useful!

On my app, I solved this by creating a new side container that runs a cron job, every 5 minutes with the following command:

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

(note that you need the side container to run in privileged mode)

It works nicely and has the advantage of being predictable: every 5 minutes, your memory cache will be cleared.